# How to allow users to cancel their own account?

Tags: 8, users

I gave the permission `cancel own user account` to authenticated users.

Now they can see a `Cancel account` button on their profile edit.

But when they click on that button, a confirmation form opens. That is fine.

On the confirmation form, when they click on the `Cancel account`, they are redirected to their profile page with a message

`A confirmation request to cancel your account has been sent to your email address.`

I want to change this functionality. When they click on cancel account, they should not receive a confirmation cancellation email. Their account should be deleted immediately and they should be gets logged out.

I tried with this code but it is not working.

`$form['user_cancel_confirm']['#default_value'] = FALSE;`

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/cancel_account and have you read through https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2854884 and the follow up issues?

Comment: Yes I checked that issue on drupal.org and the followup issue but that patch is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the [Cancel Account Separate Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/cancel_account) module does exactly what you want. It provides a form that finally [calls `user_cancel` with the current user's UID as parameter](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/cancel_account/blob/8.x-1.0/src/Form/CancelAccountForm.php#L148).

> This is a very simple, lightweight module that provides cancel user
>   account separate form and adds it to user edit form by default if user
>   has cancel account permissions and edits his own account.

Comment: Will check the cancel account separate Form module now.